# Can you use HAVING clause on a column not listed in the GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

I have this query that i've been working on, the solution i found is a having for an AVERAGE result per Pecheur (fisherman), yes this is a bit cheasy it's a school project. I basically need the name and adress of every fisherman who have a minimum of two charges (FRAIS) on every of their contract (CONTRAT), and an average of 2 fish catches (prises) per year between 2000 and 2002 inclusively. necessary tables are listed in the from with JOINs, my question is, can i use HAVING AVG(x) although x is not listed in the Select nor in the group by, but only appears in a table in the FROM section. Please note that i don't have a real DB to test the query.

```
SELECT  pecheur.NOM as nom_Pecheur, 
        pecheur.ADRESSE as adresse

FROM    TP1_PECHEUR as pecheur
        INNER JOIN TP1_CONTRAT as contrat on pecheur.ID_PECHEUR=contrat.ID_PECHEUR
        INNER JOIN TP1_FRAIS_CONTRAT as frais_contrat on contrat.ID_CONTRAT=frais_contrat.ID_CONTRAT
        INNER JOIN TP1_FRAIS as frais on frais_contrat.ID_FRAIS=frais.ID_FRAIS
        INNER JOIN TP1_DECLARATION_PRISE as declaration_prise on pecheur.ID_PECHEUR=declaration_prise.ID_PECHEUR
        INNER JOIN TP1_PRISE as prise on declaration_prise.ID_DECLARATION_PRISE=prise.ID_DECLARATION_PRISE

WHERE   frais_contrat.ID IN ( SELECT  TP1_FRAIS_CONTRAT.ID, COUNT(*) as NB_FRAIS
                              FROM    TP1_FRAIS_CONTRAT
                              GROUP BY TP1_FRAIS_CONTRAT.ID
                              HAVING NB_FRAIS >= 2 )
        AND declaration_prise.DATE_DECLARATION BETWEEN '01-01-2000' AND '31-12-2002'

GROUP BY  nom_Pecheur

HAVING    AVG(prise.NOMBRE_POISSON) > 2;
```

Comment: Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4 Now you have a real DB with which to test your query. :)

Comment: No, you _can't_ use a column in `HAVING` which did not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (otherwise Oracle won't have that information for the group).  But you _can_ write your query in a different way to achieve the same logic.

Answer (score 5):

> ...my question is, can i use HAVING AVG(x) although x is not listed in
>   the Select nor in the group by...

The short answer is 'Yes'.

```
SELECT
  ColB,
  ColC
FROM Testing
GROUP BY ColB, ColC
HAVING AVG(ColA) > 4;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79358/2)